# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url giving 127.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, iis-express, azure-ad-b2b

I created a vanilla ASP.NET MVC AAD Authenticated application in Visual Studio 2017. It includes the following:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                            var graphUri = new Uri(AAD_GRAPH_URI);
                            var serviceRoot = new Uri(graphUri, tenantId);
                            this.aadClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await AcquireGraphAPIAccessToken(AAD_GRAPH_URI, authContext, credential));
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
});
```

For a while `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` returns `https://localhost:44345/` as is listed in the browser, and configured in Visual Studio for IIS Express.

**However after a while it starts returning `http://127.0.0.1/` instead!** This results in the AzureAD auth returning the production URL instead of the localhost development URL.

I could hard code the development URL, but it is supposed to be dynamic so that it just works wherever I deploy it.

**Why is IIS Express returning `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of `https://localhost:44345/` on my development box? And how do I get it to return the correct value.**
`

Comment: And the URL you are passing in the browser on the dev box is `localhost:44345`?

Comment: Yes it is localhost:44345

Comment: And your browser request the site directly with no proxy server in the middle?

Comment: Yes, Its hosted in IIS Express started by Visual Studio..

Comment: Same thing on IIS Express

Comment: It happens on app initialization

Comment: Did you ever find an aswer to this?